# When I run client-server program I get ArrayIndexOutofBoundException

Tags: java, networking, client-server

I'm writing my first java client/server program which just establishes a connection with the server and When I run program IP address and port number should be printed. but When I run Server program I get an error.

Server.java

```
package serverpro;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Server{
 static InetAddress ip;
 public static final String HOST="localhost";
 public static final int PORT= 4444; 


public static void main(String a[]) throws Exception {
System.out.println("starting server..");
System.out.println("Initializing Connection..");

try (
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
        Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();

        //BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        //PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
) {
    ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
    System.out.println("InetAdress " + ip.getHostAddress() + " : " + clientSocket.getPort());


} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println("Exception in starting server: " + e.getMessage());
}
}
 }
```

Client.java

```
package serverpro;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

 public class Client {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
try (
        Socket client = new Socket(Server.HOST, Server.PORT);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
        BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
) {
    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = stdIn.readLine()) != null) {

        if ("exit".equals(inputLine)) {
            out.println("exit");
            break;
        }

        out.println(inputLine);
        out.flush();

        final String response = in.readLine();
        System.out.println(response);
    }
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    System.err.println("Don't know about host: localhost.");
    System.exit(1);
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to: localhost.");
    System.exit(1);
}
```

}
}

Now When I run ServerProgram first I get below output

run:

```
Entered server console..
Initializing Connection..
```

but When I run Client Output then it's showing null

run:

Comment: Probably you haven't passed port(command line arg) to GreetingServer while running.

Comment: Can you please write whole line so that I can get idea. How to write with port number?

Comment: how are you running it? through command line or some IDE?

Comment: I am running through IDE. When I run the program port number and IP address should automatically generate without entering anything manually

Comment: Typically IDEs support passage of program/VM arguments while launching programs. google it for your IDE.

Comment: @poojagajera if you want to automatically assign a port number, why have you written code that takes the port number from arguments?

Comment: Ok let me make changes and get back to you

Comment: I have made changes in code see my code above. but still I am not getting output as expected

Answer (score 0):

I guess you do not start the program with any arguments, so your `args` array is empty. Start the program with arguments or find a different way to get the server name and port.

Comment: Can you please suggest me way that it should start automatically without argument ?

Comment: @poojagajera Using a properties file.

Comment: No I am not getting will you please write a piece of code so that I can understand. thank you

Comment: Hii what changes do I need to make in order to start program with argument.

Comment: I have made changes in code see my code above. but still I am not getting output as expected –

Answer (score 0):

I didnt get anything from your description, but if you want your server to reply what you will wright into command prompt you should change your "in.readLine"

```
 while (x) {
        reply= stdIn.readLine();
        if(reply!=null)
        {
            x=false;
        }
    }
```

Also if you want ip address and port to be printed you should print it, lol

```
System.out.println("InetAdress " + echoSocket.getInetAddress() + ":" + echoSocket.getPort());
```

Comment: In which file do I need to make this change. server or client ?

Comment: In server. After the declaration of _BufferedReader stdIn_. You just mixed up your _in_ bufferedReader, and _stdIn_ BufferedReader, I guess.

Comment: Can you please write whole piece of code so that I can get better ides

Comment: can I share git hub link with you ?

Comment: Hii I have made changes in my code see above code again.

Answer (score 0):

check this

```
public class Server {
    public static final String HOST="localhost";
    public static final int PORT= 4444;  

public static void main(String a[]) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("starting server..");
    System.out.println("Initializing Connection..");
    try (
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
    ) {
        System.out.println("start");
        System.out.println("client: " + clientSocket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress());

        while (true) {
            System.out.println("waiting request...");
            final String request = in.readLine();

            if ("exit".equals(request)) {
                System.out.println("exit command");
                break;
            }
            System.out.println("received: " + request);
            final String response = "server:" + request;
            out.println(response);

            System.out.println("sent back: " + response);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Exception in starting server: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

```
public class Client {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try (
            Socket client = new Socket(Server.HOST, Server.PORT);
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
            BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    ) {
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = stdIn.readLine()) != null) {

            if ("exit".equals(inputLine)) {
                out.println("exit");
                break;
            }

            out.println(inputLine);
            out.flush();

            final String response = in.readLine();
            System.out.println(response);
        }
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.err.println("Don't know about host: localhost.");
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to: localhost.");
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Hiii when I run program I should get ip address and port number automatically without manually entering anything. this doesn't work here.

Comment: when I run my program.I should get server name and port number

Comment: HI What do you mean without manually entering? passing host/port through program arguments?

Comment: when I run my server program I should get IP address and port number automatically.

Comment: I should get IP address of my computer and port number when I run server program.

Comment: Ok local Ip address program can get, but should program find free port? may be it can be static ?

Comment: we can use any port whatever we want. that's up to us.

Comment: When I run server program. I want to get client's IP address and port number

Comment: added to Server client address `System.out.println("client: " + clientSocket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress());` server already knows port. Useless to print

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
java -cp /path/toCompiled/code greetingserver.GreetingClient serverName 8080
```

should print "Connecting to serverName on port 8080

Comment: When I run my program port number and IP address should automatically without writing through cmd. it should run in IDE only

Comment: I have made changes in code see my code above. but still I am not getting output as expected –